# Responsive CSS media query wrong

Tags: css, responsive-design

Why does the following CSS apply on Nexus 4 which has 1280x768 resolution?

```
@media
(max-width: 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    /* this shouldn't apply on Nexus 4 */
}
```

Comment: What is the viewport set to?

Comment: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale = 1.0;" />`

Comment: The window.devicePixelRatio = 2, so 768/2 = 384 which is less than 480.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This might help to target Nexus 4:

```
@media screen and (device-width: 384px) and (device-height: 592px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)
```

(http://cssmediaqueries.com/target/LG+Nexus+4.html)

I don't know if the

```
(orientation: portrait)
```

Works on most phones so you might want to research this as I know for a while iPhone wasn't using this just the iPad only.

Comment: Ooooh, so on some devices actual pixels and CSS pixels don't match? I had no idea! Now I know and it all makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Test with `@media all` or `@media screen` instead of `@media` only.

More media queries here http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: No effect, same thing happens